# How can I add a shadow to actual screen frame on html?

Tags: html, shadow, css

How can I add a shadow to actual screen frame on html on top of other content? If it's not possible then the same question for body frame.

This doesn't work:

```
body {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #0d1f2b;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #0d1f2b;
  -o-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #0d1f2b;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #0d1f2b;
}
```

This shows a shadow on screen bounds but I can scroll it up by scrolling the content of the page:

```
.screen {
  position:absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #0d1f2b;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #0d1f2b;
  -o-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #0d1f2b;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #0d1f2b;
}

  <div class="screen"></div>
```

Comment: have you tried to make it position:fixed?

Comment: Joao, unfortunately it doesn't work on iPad when keyboard is visible:( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659891/fixed-position-div-freezes-on-page-ipad

Comment: check if this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970389/ios-5-fixed-positioning-and-virtual-keyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]    body {
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 45px 45px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 45px 45px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);;
            box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px 15px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);;
        }

note :change values according to your requirement

Comment: its work in the case you scroll any div inside body of page..and I thought you want css for body not for your div...thats why provided solution...

Comment: But I don't see any shadow with the provided code for `body`.

Comment: see the image...if it is your case...I am getting shadow like this

Comment: Thanks. But it doesn't work on my page. Really don't know why yet.

Comment: you are trying in which browser...it might be not working in older browser..I guess..

Comment: I found out that issue was caused by javascript logic and fixed it. But body shadow doesn't fill with a shadow the full screen:(

Comment: `min-height: 100%;` for body helps me!

Comment: Marked your answer as right but it works right only with `min-height: 100%;`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for **Joao Palma**'s comment:

```
.screen {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #0d1f2b;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #0d1f2b;
  -o-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #0d1f2b;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #0d1f2b;
}

  <div class="screen"></div>
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work on iPad when keyboard is visible:( Relative question: [fixed position div freezes on page (iPad)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659891/fixed-position-div-freezes-on-page-ipad)